# beginner group by question, syntax related

Tags: sql

I have a booking table that holds multiple guests and all the bookings they have made throughout the years.

I am supposed to show, the guestsID and the start year of their bookings and the number of bookings they placed if its greater than 5.

```
SELECT guestid, YEAR(startdate) AS 'Year' 
FROM BOOKING 
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
```

How do I get the count of all of the individual guest ids? to show how many times they have made reservations?

Comment: On a side note: It should be `AS "Year"` in standard SQL. Some DBMS have another syntax like `AS [Year]` or `AS \`Year\``. And you can always make this just `AS Year` of course, if you don't care about upper/lower case in the column title. (Please tag your SQL requests always with the DBMS you are using.) Single quotes are for string literals. Don't confuse the two. In some situations this could lead to undesired results. Here is a demo for a wrong query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3c1eda95bfe88fbbd9348063627210a

Answer (score 2):

You can write this way:

```
SELECT guest_id, count(guest_id), YEAR(startdate) AS 'Year' 
FROM BOOKING 
WHERE 
GROUP BY guest_id, year(Startdate)
HAVING count(guest_id) > 5;
```

A sample data set to filter `count >= 2`

```
mysql> select * from 
    -> booking;
+----------+------------+------+
| guest_id | startdate  | flag |
+----------+------------+------+
|        1 | 2022-01-02 |    1 |
|        1 | 2021-02-02 |    1 |
|        1 | 2021-03-02 |    1 |
|        2 | 2022-01-02 |    1 |
|        2 | 2020-01-02 |    1 |
|        3 | 2022-01-02 |    1 |
|        4 | 2021-01-02 |    1 |
+----------+------------+------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select guest_id, count(guest_id), year(startdate) from booking group by guest_id, year(startdate);
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| guest_id | count(guest_id) | year(startdate) |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|        1 |               2 |            2021 |
|        1 |               1 |            2022 |
|        2 |               1 |            2020 |
|        2 |               1 |            2022 |
|        3 |               1 |            2022 |
|        4 |               1 |            2021 |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select guest_id, count(guest_id), year(startdate) from booking group by guest_id, year(startdate) having count(guest_id) > 1;
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| guest_id | count(guest_id) | year(startdate) |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|        1 |               2 |            2021 |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Great example..!!

Comment: Thanks @DaminiSuthar, pls upvote if its useful

Comment: Sure I will do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT B.guestid, B.count, B.YEAR(startdate) AS 'Year' 
FROM (select B.*,
             count(*) over (partition by guestid) as count  
      from BOOKING B
     ) B
WHERE B.count > 5
```

Or In other query you can use multiple group by

```
    SELECT  guestid, COUNT(guestid),  YEAR(startdate) AS 'Year' 
        FROM BOOKING
        GROUP BY  guestid , YEAR(startdate)
        Having COUNT(guestid) > 5
```